# Explaining the index expression of a random variable list

Tags: variables, math, random, indexing, discrete-mathematics

This is my question, I have random variables with index **i = 1, 2,...,k**.
I want to understand what this expression **l = k - i**, means in a simple form.
I think l is the total number of the variables from 1,...,k.
Can some assist me to interpret what l is from the expression above?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleansing my crystal ball, I see the next:

```
l = k - i
```

is number of items after i-th one.

```
 1   2   3     4   5  :   k
|__________| |______|
     i          l
```